# Apparent creation of array from another array?

Tags: python, arrays, scipy

I have the following code snippet from [SciPy](http://scipy-central.org/item/36/2/error-estimates-for-fit-parameters-resulting-from-least-squares-fits-using-bootstrap-resampling):

```
resDat = data[scipy.random.randint(0,N,(N,))]
```

What I try to understand is how and why this line works. the `randint` function seems to return a list of `N` integer values in the range of the data indizes, so what I interpret this line of code to do is that `resDat` will become an array with `N` random values from `data`. 
I tried to replicate this in the Python shell:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
b=[1,2]
c=a[b]
```

However if I try this I get - on line 3 - the error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

Which to my knowledge means, that I need to give it a number instead of a list. But why is the line at the top working then? I have the feeling I am missing some important distinction, but can't figure out which one.
Coming from a mainly .NET background the first line looks a bit like a LinQ statement, but is it comparable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe data would be of type -

```
numpy.ndarray
```

You can do `type(data)` it should comes out as `numpy.ndarray` .

Also , `scipy.random.randint()` also returns a value of type `numpy.ndarray` .

You may not be able to do `lst[[1,2]]` , but you can use `numpy.ndarray` as a subscript to another `numpy.ndarray` .

A Simple example -

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([10,15,20,25,30])
print(data[np.array([1,2,3])])
>> array([15,20,25])
```

Comment: Hell, that's why I hate implicit declarations. That explains it then, thanks.